# jQuery animations don't run separately

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following content:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="update">1.</div>
    <div class="update">2.</div>
    <div class="update">3.</div>
    <div class="update">4.</div>
</div>
```

I want to animate every `div` with the `update` class inside this `content` div. I animated them like this:

```
$('#content div.update').each(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-top': '10px',
        'opacity': 1
    }, 300);
});
```

I discovered the animations run all at once. I looked up the [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) function but it makes no sence to me at all. I found some blog articles but they make it way to complicated. Can someone give me an example of how I should queue this properly so that it animates every `div.update` one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4dbp/1)

```
$('#content div.update').each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(i*300).animate({
        'margin-top': '10px',
        'opacity': 1
    }, 300);
});
```